# Android - TextView is not updated. What goes wrong?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a pedometer.
So as can be seen, once the acceleration of one particular direction exceeds 1, the counter increments by 1. Then I wanna display the count number in the textView.
However, the textView is always displayed as "TextView" instead of the desired number.

Any idea? Thanks!

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    Button startButton;
    Button pauseButton;
    Button resetButton;
    TextView textView;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private long lastUpdate;

    private boolean isCalibrated = false;
    private int referrenceAxis;
    private int stepCounts = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // start button
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        // pause button
        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        // reset button
        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        init();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void init() {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (isCalibrated && (actualTime - lastUpdate > 500)) {
                if (event.values[referrenceAxis] > 1) {
                    stepCounts++;
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(stepCounts));
                }
            }
        lastUpdate = actualTime;    
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
            if (!isCalibrated) {

                if ((event.values[0] >= event.values[1])&&(event.values[0] >= event.values[2]))
                    referrenceAxis = 0;
                if ((event.values[1] >= event.values[0])&&(event.values[1] >= event.values[2]))
                    referrenceAxis = 1;
                if ((event.values[2] >= event.values[0])&&(event.values[2] >= event.values[1]))
                    referrenceAxis = 2;

                isCalibrated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register this class as a listener for the sensors
        sensorManager
                .registerListener(this, sensorManager
                        .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // unregister listener
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

}
```

XML is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/textview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/step_mumber"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: has your onsersonrchanged fired?? please check that too

Comment: please post ur xml also

Comment: Yes, we need the xml to help you!

Comment: oh oh! I see. Will do it now. Do please help! :)

Comment: @ArunAntony  XML is up. Please help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Here :

```
textView.setText(stepCounts); //<<<
```

you are passing Integer Value to TextView.setText method that's why you are getting `Resources$NotFoundException` . show Integer value in TextView as:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(stepCounts));
```

Comment: makes sense. But please see the updated question. I have modified as so. But it still displays "TextView" instead of the number.

Comment: if you are not setting latest value in textview then debug your app and check control flow when app is running it's going in if block here you are changing TextView value.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand. Could you pls elaborate? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler just use ""+number in setText() method.

Comment: Is any exception thrown what does log cat say?

Comment: no exception. Just the TextView does not show the number. Instead it show TextView....

Comment: waht do you mean by editable? If u mean "does it change?". Then no, it always shows "TextView"

Comment: No I meant option Editable you can specify it in XML, but since you don't know about it I will guess you haven't used it. So no problem there. :D In method onSensorChanged, are you apsolutely sure that your code comes to that line to setText, have you checked it with debugger? Does it pass those 2 nested if-s?

Comment: i got it right man. my onSensorChanged even failed to be called... no idea why